# MS Access Relationships and Linking Data

Tags: database, ms-access, database-design, relationship

I have several raw materials, stored by their part numbers (unique) in a table (other fields include description, units, quantity, date bought etc.) An assembly (stored in a separate table) requires several of these raw materials in order to construct it. These raw materials are not exclusive to any certain assembly - there could be multiple different assemblies which use the same raw material.

I have thought of creating a separate table where there is a field for the assembly and one for raw material - allowing them to be linked. However, this means that for one assembly that has for example three raw materials, there would be three records created with the assembly field repeated (not ideal, as it would result in a very large database).

My limited understanding of relationships tells me that it's not possible to link these without a common primary key, and even if there was one, I can't see how I would link multiple raw materials to one assembly. Given that users would over time, add new raw materials and new assemblies to the two tables, this adds complexity that I, with my limited understanding of MS Access, am not sure can be accomplished.

Maybe there is a better way of storing the data or maybe SQL in MS Access can accomplish this? But I am even more clueless with SQL than Access.

Any assistance and advice is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Look up some tutorials in "Beginning with Microsoft Access", "Introduction to SQL" and similar. There are lots to be found for the browsing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is very possible, and something that has been done lots of times before.

Imagine your raw materials table looks something like this:

```
+---+--------+
| 1 | Metal  |
+---+--------+
| 2 | Wood   |
+---+--------+
| 3 | Rubber |
+---+--------+
```

And your assemblies look something like this:

```
+---+-------+
| 1 | Bike  |
+---+-------+
| 2 | Table |
+---+-------+
```

Then, to create a many-to-many relationship, you need a third table that combines the two (columns `AssemblyID`, `MaterialID`):

```
+---+---+
| 1 | 1 |
+---+---+
| 1 | 3 |
+---+---+
| 2 | 2 |
+---+---+
```

As you can see, the bike requires rubber and metal, and the table only requires wood.

There are a lot of more detailed guides on many-to-many relationships in Access. But the core concept is you need an extra table to link the two together.

Comment: Would it be possible to link without having to have a new record for each raw material required in the assembly? For multiple complex assemblies (some with 20+ raw materials) this would mean 20+ records just for one assembly, resulting in a very large database very quickly. It's likely there would be issues with indexing/speed?

Comment: It's possible but not recommended. The records per raw material are really, really small (only 2 numbers, or 3 if you want to add a primary key, but you could use a unique compound index of both columns removing the need for another identifier). That means size and indexes are really not an issue. As said in the question, it's also a very common technique, so databases are optimized for this.